# Why do certain Time comparisons have counterintuitive results?

Tags: ruby, time, ruby-2.1

In Ruby 2.1.2, I can successfully compare the result of `Time.parse` and `Time.utc` for the same time, and it returns the expected `true`:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43Z") == Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43)
=> true
```

However, this same comparison counterintuitively returns `false` when the second value is not an integer:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z") == Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1)
=> false
```

This is despite the fact that the second values are still integers and are still equivalent:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z").sec
=> 43
Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1).sec
=> 43
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z").sec == Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1).sec
=> true
```

Moreover, the comparison results in `true` between successive calls of the same methods:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z") == Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z")
=> true
Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1) == Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1)
=> true
```

Why is this so? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please rephrase your wording. It is misleading/confusing. Where you claim comparison fails, it isn't failing, it is succeeding and is returning `false`.

Comment: This appears to be a pure Ruby question, in which case you should  remove all reference to Rails, especially the Rails tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby compares fractional seconds as well as seconds when comparing times. For some reason your times receive different fractional seconds:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z").subsec
# => (1/10)
Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1).subsec
# => (14073748835533/140737488355328)
```

Comment: Sounds like the usual floating point shenanigans- 43.1 can't be represented exactly.

Comment: I.e. Precision.  When comparing 2 numbers that only matter if they are "close enough" (i.e. floating point and time values), you have to make sure they are within acceptable bounds.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are running into an issue with precision.  The reason the integer seconds compare works is due to the precision of integers, and Ruby performed a `.to_i` on the parsed version for you.

Underlying the Time class is an integer that represents a very precise integer number, and parsing and explicit values might be treated just differently enough to cause problems.  If sub-second precision is not important to you, then it would be best to compare seconds:

```
Time.parse("2015-02-09T22:38:43.1Z").to_i == Time.utc(2015, 2, 9, 22, 38, 43.1).to_i
```

In the above case you are comparing seconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)

Another option would be to create a function to compare two times within a certain precision.  Many unit testing frameworks provide that feature.  Essentially if T1 == T2 within 0.1 seconds, it's good enough.

The easiest way to do a "within" comparison would be like this:

```
def within(time1, time2, precision)
    return (time1 - time2).abs < precision
end
```

NOTE: the above works with time, floating points, and fractions.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why my answer was downvoted?  It is correct.  The `Time.parse` and `Time.utc` methods are logically similar, but due to precision and rounding issues have differing fractional values.  However, if 0.1 second granularity is all you need, they would be equivalent if you tested for that.